# How to fire a click event on Syncfusion's TreeView

Tags: xamarin.forms, treeview, syncfusion

Menu.xaml

```
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <ContentPage Title="Menu" Padding="0">
        <ContentPage.Content>
            <StackLayout>
                <Grid BackgroundColor="LightGreen">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Label Grid.Column="1"
                               Grid.Row="2"
                               Text="DEC App"
                               TextColor="White"
                               FontSize="Large"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <syncfusion:SfTreeView x:Name="treeView">
                        <syncfusion:SfTreeView.Nodes>
                            <!--1st Menu-->
                            <treeviewengine:TreeViewNode Content="Menu 1">
                                <treeviewengine:TreeViewNode.ChildNodes>
                                    <treeviewengine:TreeViewNode Content="Menu 1.1">
                                        <!--SubMenu 1-->
                                    </treeviewengine:TreeViewNode>
                                    <treeviewengine:TreeViewNode Content="Menu 1.2">
                                        <!--SubMenu 2-->
                                        <treeviewengine:TreeViewNode.ChildNodes>
                                            <treeviewengine:TreeViewNode Content="Menu 1.2.1"/>
                                            <!--SubMenu 2.1-->
                                            <treeviewengine:TreeViewNode Content="Menu 1.2.2"/>
                                            <!--SubMenu 2.2-->
                                        </treeviewengine:TreeViewNode.ChildNodes>
                                    </treeviewengine:TreeViewNode>
                                </treeviewengine:TreeViewNode.ChildNodes>
                            </treeviewengine:TreeViewNode>
                        </syncfusion:SfTreeView.Nodes>
                    </syncfusion:SfTreeView>
                </StackLayout>
            </ContentPage.Content>
        </ContentPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

Menu.xaml.cs

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace MasterDetailDemo
{
     [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
     public partial class Menu : MasterDetailPage
{
    public Menu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Detail = new NavigationPage(new MenuDetail());
    }
```

I used Syncfusion's SfTreeView to create this menu here

[TreeView in Master Page Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMECu.png)

But i don't know how to create a click event on it, i tried reading through all of Syncfusion's Documents but it didn't help much. Thanks in advance

Comment: according to the docs, it has a SelectionChanging and SelectionChanged events.  https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sftreeview/getting-started#selection

Comment: Is there a way to create clicked event on individual Child Node in the treeview ?

Or i just keep reading "Selection" ?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Through the SelectionChanged event or Item Tap event, you should know which node you are clicking and then perform your own actions.

Comment: I wanna able to navigate each sub menu to another content page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add an `ItemTapped` event to `syncfusion:SfTreeView`:

```
  <syncfusion:SfTreeView x:Name="treeView" ItemTapped="treeView_ItemTapped">
                        <syncfusion:SfTreeView.Nodes>
                            <!--1st Menu-->
                            <treeviewengine:TreeViewNode Content="Menu 1">
                                //...
                            </treeviewengine:TreeViewNode>
                        </syncfusion:SfTreeView.Nodes>
                    </syncfusion:SfTreeView>
```

Then in the `treeView_ItemTapped`, you can know which `node` you are clicking and navigate to corresponding Page:

```
private void treeView_ItemTapped(object sender, Syncfusion.XForms.TreeView.ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{

    var TappedNode = e.Node as TreeViewNode;

    Console.WriteLine(TappedNode.Content);


    if (TappedNode.Content is "Menu 1")
    {
        Detail = new NavigationPage(new ItemsPage());
        IsPresented = false;
    }
    else if (TappedNode.Content is "Menu 1.1")
    {
        Detail = new NavigationPage(new AboutPage());
        IsPresented = false;
    }
    else if (TappedNode.Content is "Menu 1.2")
    {
        //...
    }
    else
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

I can share you a sample if you need. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: @MatthewKyrielight [Sample here](https://github.com/XfHua/SfTreeView-node). I just create a new project with `MasterDetail template` and modified codes in `MainPage`.

Comment: In my project i used a Content Page and just turn it into a Master Detail page

I'll Compress my Project and send it to you if you want

Comment: Sure, you can upload to Github and share the link here.

Comment: First time using GitHub, but meh, i'll try what i can

Comment: @MatthewKyrielight It's easy. I will check once you shared.

Comment: Thanks, give me some time, and i'll let you know once i manage to Upload my project. P.S: im working on Android

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rkMXFCeTGgjK7ltUKR8Bp-S0b_egkWmk

Comment: That's all i could do

Comment: @MatthewKyrielight What's your problem? The SfTreeView does not show in iOS? You have to add `SfTreeViewRenderer.Init();` in `AppDelegate` as mentioned [here](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sftreeview/getting-started#ios). It works perfectly on my side in both Android and iOS emulator.

Comment: I mostly code in the portable part, i haven't touch anything there yet
Also, there's no problem so far, it just wanna be able to navigate to seperated pages

Comment: And as i mentioned above, i only did Android so far

Comment: @MatthewKyrielight The DetailPage do change when you click different node. Which page you navigating to depends on the if-else statement you write in treeView_ItemTapped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tap command of syncfusion xamarin treeview.
https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/treeview/mvvm#tap-command

In another way, you can use ItemTapped event also,
https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/cref_files/xamarin/Syncfusion.SfTreeView.XForms~Syncfusion.XForms.TreeView.SfTreeView~ItemTapped_EV.html

Comment: It's still confused to me, and i couldn't really solved it

Answer (score 0):

We would like to inform that you can use either TreeView’s ItemTapped event or TapCommand to get notification when treeview node clicked in view. We have attached the sample and code snippet based for your reference below.

Sample Link :  https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/254006/ze/TreeviewMasterDetail-384415166

To know more about TapCommand and ItemTapped event, please refer our documentation.

https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/treeview/mvvm#tap-command
https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/treeview/interactivity#tapped-eventhttps://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/treeview/interactivity#tapped-event

```
public class ContentPageBehavior : Behavior<ContentPage>
{
        protected override void OnAttachedTo(ContentPage bindable)
        {
            TreeView = bindable.FindByName<SfTreeView>("treeView");
            TreeView.ItemTapped += TreeView_ItemTapped;
            base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
        }

        private void TreeView_ItemTapped(object sender, Syncfusion.XForms.TreeView.ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            var TappedNode = e.Node as TreeViewNode;
            App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Message","Tapped Item : "+ TappedNode.Content, "Ok");
        }

}
```

Comment: Apparently i can't download the file. 

Access Denied it seem

Comment: Also, instead of noltification, how about navigating to a new page when the user tap on a menu ?